# keypress with backspace and delete

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm sure all the web developers have encountered a scenario where they needed to check the press of all the characters keys along with backspace & delete.

For instance, To display an error message as soon as user enters some invalid key. For this, I would continuously listen to some key event to check for the invalid key.

Since, keypress doesn't work for backspace and delete keys, we use keydown event. But, the problem with keydown event is it would fire the event on all keys including Alt, Ctrl, Tab, etc., the keys for which I don't need to execute the logic for finding out the invalid keys.

The common workaround to this we use and see is we filter out the non-required keys by checking the keycode.

So, I wanted to know if there was some other way as in some other key event in order to not list down all the non-required keys in the above scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register two separate event listeners e.g. `(keydown)` for <kbd>Delete</kbd> & <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and `(keypress)` for everything else in your component's initialization as shown below:

```
  ngOnInit() {

    addEventListener('keypress', (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
      // Execute your logic here.
        console.log(event);
    });

    addEventListener('keydown', (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
      // Check for allowed keys on keydown
      if (event.key === 'Delete' || event.key === 'Backspace') {
        // Execute your logic here.
        console.log(event);
      }
    });

  }
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't know why didn't think like that. It does reduce the pain of listing down all the non-required keys, keeping in mind Windows and Mac both.
Though, I would wait for a day or 2 to see if anyone has any better solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Already Answer has been given so there is no much change in it.

Instead of check the key with their name. I have checked with KeyCode because some time/case browser return the **event.key** as **empty** so in-order to prevent the case we can go with keyCode.

You can register the event by **addEventListener** with **keyPress** or **KeyDown** and check the Keycode of **Delete** or space bar and **return** if condition get matched
find the link for all key code : [KeyCodes List](https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)

```js
 addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
      // Check for allowed keys on keydown with Code
      if (event.keyCode === 32 || event.keyCode === 46) {
        console.log("Invalid key:",event.code);
        return;
      }
    });
```

Hope, it will solve your problem some extend.

Comment: @Suyash Gupta Sir, You can review the solution  and let me know feedback

Comment: I'm already using `event.code`. Thank you, anyways!